# How can I install ojdbc6 on eclipse, getting error: unknown lifecycle phase "mvn"?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to install ojdbc6 on my home computer so I can work on a project from another location.

I have downloaded the `ojdbc6.jar` file but when I try to run Maven build with the goal:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\alex\Downloads/ojdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I get the error:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]"

I have downloaded `apache-maven-3.3.9` and have set the environment variable to the folder, and the path to the `/bin`.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be and how I can fix it as I need to work on this over the weekend?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `mvn` from the beginning of the string:

```
install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\alex\Downloads/ojdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

instead of:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\alex\Downloads/ojdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I'm guessing you are executing this command using the Eclipse Maven tools, which will already apply the `mvn` command.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks! however it's still saying "Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3" do I need to do anything else for the pom.xml to find it?

Comment: I've realised it was version 11.2.0 I installed, so just needed to alter the reference.